# No result coming out after loading on excel file for html

Tags: javascript, html, json, xlsx

```js
function calculate() {
  const selectedCategory = document.querySelector('input[name="category"]:checked').value;
  const costing = parseFloat(document.getElementById('costing').value);
  const profitMargin = parseFloat(document.getElementById('profit-margin').value);
  let sellingPrice = document.getElementById('selling-price').value;

  if (isNaN(costing) || isNaN(profitMargin)) {
    alert("Please enter numbers!");
    return;
  }

  if (sellingPrice) {
    sellingPrice = parseFloat(sellingPrice);
  }

  const suggestedSellingPrice = costing * ((100 + profitMargin) / 100);

  // Load the SheetJS library
  var XLSX = require('xlsx');

  // Load the Excel file and calculate the average selling price of the selected category
  fetch('product.xlsx')
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(data => {
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'array'
      });
      var firstSheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
      var jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(firstSheet);

      let total = 0;
      let count = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        if (jsonData[i].category == selectedCategory) {
          total += jsonData[i].price;
          count++;
        }
      }
      const averageSellingPrice = total / count;

      let resultMessage = "";
      if (!sellingPrice) {
        resultMessage = "The suggested selling price is: " + suggestedSellingPrice + "<br> The average selling price in the database file is: " + averageSellingPrice;
      } else if (sellingPrice == suggestedSellingPrice) {
        resultMessage = "The selling price is REASONABLE." + "<br> The average selling price in the database file is: " + averageSellingPrice;
      } else if (sellingPrice > suggestedSellingPrice) {
        resultMessage = "The selling price is NOT REASONABLE as it exceeded the profit margin, the suggested selling price is: $" + suggestedSellingPrice.toFixed(2) + "<br> The average selling price in the database file is: " + averageSellingPrice;
      } else {
        resultMessage = "The selling price is NOT REASONABLE as it has not enough profit margin, the suggested selling price is: $" + suggestedSellingPrice.toFixed(2) + "<br> The average selling price in the database file is: " + averageSellingPrice;
      }
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultMessage;
    });
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Suggested Selling Price Calculator</h1><br><br><br>

<h2 align="center">Please select a product category:</h2>
<form align="center">
  <input type="radio" id="category1" name="category" value="1" required>
  <label for="category1">Apparel</label>

  <input type="radio" id="category2" name="category" value="2">
  <label for="category2">Beauty & Skincare</label>

  <input type="radio" id="category3" name="category" value="3">
  <label for="category3">Food & Beverages</label>

  <input type="radio" id="category4" name="category" value="3">
  <label for="category4">Household Products</label>

  <input type="radio" id="category5" name="category" value="3">
  <label for="category5">Baby Care Products</label><br /><br /><br />
</form>

<br>
<form align="center">
  <label for="costing">Costing ($):</label>
  <input type="number" id="costing" name="costing" step="0.01" required><br><br>

  <label for="profit-margin">Profit Margin (%):</label>
  <input type="number" id="profit-margin" name="profit-margin" step="0.01" required><br><br>

  <label for="selling-price">Selling Price ($):</label>
  <input type="text" id="selling-price" name="selling-price" step="0.01" value="OPTIONAL"><br><br><br>

  <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br /><br /><br />
</form>

<h2 align="center">Suggested Selling Price:<br> <span id="result"></span><br></h2>
<p id="message" <br></p>
```

The ideal outcome is for user to select a category then input the costing, profit margin and their expected selling price (optional) then find out if their selling price is reasonable based on their profit margin. We will also show the average selling price based on the `price` column in the excel file.

However the result was not displayed after clicking the calculate button. What's wrong with it?

- file name: `product.xlsx`
- sheet name: product file

Comment: Have you check if you have some errors in your browser console? did you debug your code?